# conditionally change layout template for catalogsearch

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, catalogsearch

What I need to do is, if a person search for a product then if products found the layout need to be `page/2columns-left.phtml` with `layered navigation` but if there were no results then its layout should be `page/1column.phtml` and it will display `new products`, `popular products`.

One of the solution I came around is to override the `CatalogSearch/ResultController`'s `indexAction()` where I can get whether `$query->getNumResults()` is `0` or not. On that basis how could I load layout differently?

If there's another better approach to this, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Add layout handle in `catalogsearch.xml`:**

```
<NO_SEARCH_RESULTS>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--  add your blocks here-->
    </reference>
</NO_SEARCH_RESULTS>
```

**2.Load this handle in controller:**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    /**
     * some codes here
     */

    $this->loadLayout();
    if ($someValueIsTrue) {
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('NO_SEARCH_RESULTS');
        $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
        $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
    }

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: perfect! exactly the same thing what I wanted. I was missing `$this->loadLayoutUpdates();`. Can you tell me what is the order of calling these functions? Is there any blog or tutorial on it?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal see `public function loadLayout()` of `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action class`. Our logick is same as logic of this function.

Comment: I'd previously tried `$this->loadLayout('NO_SEARCH_RESULTS');` but it doesn't worked that time?

Comment: In this case `default` handle will not added to layout updates. See `public function loadLayout()` for understanding the logic.

Comment: You could also do `$this->loadLayout(array('default','NO_SEARCH_RESULTS')`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://sandersluis.com/2011/11/changing-the-page-template-in-a-magento-controller/. Hope this helps.

Comment: not the answer I'm looking for. it just tell about changing the template. and i'm looking for rendering the layout xml